# Property value expected type of string but got null

Tags: reactjs

I have an `Icon.jsx` component:

```
import React from 'react'; import { css } from 'emotion';

import ArrowRight from "./arrow-right.svg";

export const iconTypes = {
    arrowRight: 'ARROW_RIGHT',
    //arrowLeft: "ARROW_LEFT", }

const iconSrc = {
    ARROW_RIGHT: ArrowRight,
    ARROW_LEFT: ArrowLeft, }


export default ({ type }) => {
    return (
        <Icon>
            <img src={iconSrc[type]} />
        </Icon>
    )
};
```

And an `Icon.jsx' story:

```
import React from "react";
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react";
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions";
import Icon from "../components/Icon/Index";
import { iconTypes } from "../components/Icon/Index";


storiesOf("Icon", module)
    .add("with text", () => (
        <Icon type={iconTypes.leftArrow}>
            </Icon>
    ));
```

I keep getting the following error on the `Icon.jxs` component:

```
 Property value expected type of string but got null
```

But I can't figure it out, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 'ArrowLeft' is not defined in your code (ArrowRight refers to a svg file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was do to the `ES6` syntax, that works fine:

```
export default function Icon({ type }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={iconSrc[type]} />
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using leftArrow in `<Icon type={iconTypes.leftArrow}></Icon>` which is not defined and thus `type={undefined}` and passing undefined or null will cause you the error as you've specified.

> Property value expected type of string but got null

The fix is to use defined type of arrow:

```
<Icon type={iconTypes.ARROW_LEFT}></Icon>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting a compilation error on the `Icon.jsx` component itself regardless to the call in the `Icon` story.